# check if link doesnt redirect to standard page through python urllib2

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, screen-scraping, urllib2

I am trying to check through loop what all links are valid against which are not valid and are redirecting to some standard page

```
import urllib2
import csv



i=18509
yyy = csv.writer(open('valid_links.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"',lineterminator="\n")

while i!=0:
   print i
   url="http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private  /snapshot.asp?privcapId="+str(i)
   request = urllib2.Request(url)
   request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'
   response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
   it=response.info()

   #page = urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=2).geturl()
   yyy.writerow([url,it['Content-Length']])
   i=i+1
```

I have more than 200M pages to check, can there be more efficient way?

Comment: You may try to use response code. If it is 200 or 302 or 500, etc.

Comment: but redirect will be again valid page so will it have different response code?

Comment: Yes, it may have a different response code. But this would help you identify direct hits and redirects. You may deal with redirects in a different way. Say, you may take the redirect URL and get it's response code, or something like that.